# How would I capitalize every other letter in a str?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.2

So I have been messing with python and I thought it would be a good idea to find a way to create every other letter capitalized. I got inspired from [Homestuck](http://www.mspaintadventures.com/?s=6&p=003912) and Gamzee's quirk and all.
So thank you very much for any help you can provide!

Comment: what do you mean by "every other letter"?

Comment: I think thats a great excercise. Show us what you came up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mixed = lambda s: "".join((str.upper,str.lower)[i%2](ch) for i,ch in enumerate(s))
mixed("whatchathink?")
```

returns

```
'WhAtChAtHiNk?'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip. The following function returns True if the number you pass in is even:

```
def is_even(i):
  return i % 2 == 0
```

Because even numbers happen "every other" number, you can go through each letter in a string and determine whether it should be capitalized based on whether its position is even or not.